# Error when opening crystal report in aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, crystal-reports

everyone i'm trying to load my crystal report to an aspx page on Internet Explorer 11, but I'm confused with some javascript error. I've tried to reinstall crystal report, config my aspx page and lots of directions on the others site but it doesn't working.I'm using VS 2013 and Crystal report 13.0.16.1954. Here's my error:
[image: The first error:]

[image: Then the second:]

Comment: Is your code working properly with the other browsers?

Comment: I've tried running on Firefox but it didn't work

Comment: Go tho the root directory of your website and check if there is a folder called "crystalreportviewers13"

Comment: thank you very much, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crystalreportviewers13 folder should exists in the root directory of your website.